# UI-router won't resolve promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularfire

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but it seems that my `profile` doesn't resolve by the time we get to the `MainCtrl`. The `user` however does, resolve. Am I, perhaps not fetching the profile information properly in the `Auth` Service?

Router:

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($stateProvide) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                url: '/main',
                templateUrl: 'app/main/main',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    user: function (Auth) {
                        return Auth.getUser();
                    },
                    profile: function (user) {
                        return Auth.getProfile();
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, user, profile) {    
        $scope.user = user;
        $scope.profile = profile;  <- DOESNT RESOLVE 
    });
```

Auth Service:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('Auth', function ($firebaseSimpleLogin, $firebase, FBURL) {
        var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
        var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

        var Auth = {
            user: {},
            getUser: function () {
                return auth.$getCurrentUser();
            },
            getProfile: function(uid) {
                return $firebase(ref.child('users').child(uid)).$asObject();
            }
        };
        return Auth;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
auth.$getCurrentUser()
```

returns a promise so you need a

```
.then(function(user) {
```

event before your callback complete

In your case you may just resolve on the `then`, something like

```
Auth.getUser().then(function(user){ return user; });
```

Also `$asObject()` needs `$loaded()` for it's promise

```
var obj = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
 obj.$loaded()  
 .then(function(data) {})
```

Comment: That was it! I had to have the `$loaded()` there to return a promise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this structure for your promises:

```
var fetchSomething = function (action, params) {
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'someurl to the firebase',
            data: params,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                
            return data;
        });
        return promise;
    };
```